# Weird issue with unmet dependencies when cloning package states from earlier installation on same machine

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg, aptitude

I've been doing the usual routine of saving the package selections and also marking the packages as `auto` or `manual` as outlined in the question and answer here: [Restoring all data from backup of `dpkg --set-selections '*'`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101931).

Now when I try to run `apt-get -u dselect-upgrade` I get:

```
# apt-get -u dselect-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cron : Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
 upstart : Depends: initscripts
           Depends: mountall
           Depends: ifupdown (>= 0.6.10ubuntu5)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Internal error, problem resolver broke stuff
```

The alternative `aptitude install` doesn't give me anything at all:

```
# aptitude install
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

So when I check whether `cron` and `adduser` are installed, they of course are:

```
# dpkg -l|grep -E '(adduser|cron)'
ii  adduser                           3.113ubuntu2                 add and remove users and groups
ii  cron                              3.0pl1-120ubuntu4            process scheduling daemon
```

So two questions: **what's going on and how do I resolve it?**

NB: the package selections were taken from another 12.04 installation, same architecture and everything. In fact it's a system that ran on the same machine before reinstalling on a different disk. This is the first time I run into this kind of problems when cloning an existing setup by means of package states and then copying over relevant contents from the original `/etc`.

For the second set of allegedly unmet dependencies I get:

```
# dpkg -l|grep -E '(upstart|initscripts|mountall|ifupdown)'
ii  ifupdown                          0.7~beta2ubuntu8             high level tools to configure network interfaces
ii  initscripts                       2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu11.1      scripts for initializing and shutting down the system
ii  mountall                          2.36.4                       filesystem mounting tool
ii  upstart                           1.5-0ubuntu7.2               event-based init daemon
```

So all installed.

No held packages either. Output of `aptitude search ~i|grep ^ih` is empty.

---

The system in question is a Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 installation, otherwise upgraded to latest packages. No third-party repositories configured, no package pinning or so going on.

---

btw: I would appreciate if the answer would include some pointers about what to do generally when hitting such an issue without relying in the subtly different problem resolvers in the various `dpkg` front ends. Most suggestions I've come across seem to rely solely on that and that's why I'm out of luck now. So I need to know some of the nitty gritty, too.

Comment: This is a bit late, but the first thing you should do when run into "can't be installed" messages is to run `apt-cache policy` on all the packages that appear in the error message, and then post them in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
   packages=`cat installed-software | grep -v deinstall | cut -f1`
   sudo apt-get install $packages
```

Comment: There's a [Useless Use of Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) here. Beware. You should probably do something like `grep -v deinstall installed-software | cut -f 1`.